# Sum each four rows in a column

Tags: r, dataframe, sum, rows, calculated-columns

I'm a beginner in R and I really need your help. I'm trying to get a new dataframe that stores the sum of each five rows in my columns.

For example, I have a dataframe (delta) with two columns (A,B)

```
A B   
2 3   
1 2  
3 2  
4 5  
3 7  
5 6  
2 5
```

and the output I'm looking for is

```
AA BB  
13 19  
16 22  
17 25
```

where

```
13 = row1+row2+row3+row4+row5
16 = row2+row3+row4+row5+row6
```

and so on ...

I have no idea where to start. Thanks a lot for your help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subject refers to 4 rows but the example in the question refers to 5.  We have used 5 below but if you intended 4 just replace 5 with 4 in the code.

**1) rollsum** Using the reproducible input in the Note at the end use `rollsum` .  Omit the as.data.frame if a matrix is ok as output.

```
library(zoo)

as.data.frame(rollsum(DF, 5))
##    A  B
## 1 13 19
## 2 16 22
## 3 17 25
```

**2) filter**  filter in base R works too. Note that if you have dplyr loaded it clobbers filter so in that case use stats::filter in place of filter to ensure you get the correct version.

```
setNames(as.data.frame(na.omit(filter(DF, rep(1, 5)))), names(DF))
##    A  B
## 1 13 19
## 2 16 22
## 3 17 25
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
A B
2 3
1 2
3 2
4 5
3 7
5 6
2 5"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Nice - I never realised that `stats::filter` can work on multiple columns at once. Neat.

Comment: I think using `na.omit` might cause issues if there happens to be an `NA` value however. You could avoid that with something like `n <- 5; tail(filter(DF, rep(1,n), sides=1), -(n-1))`

Comment: `filter` handles NAs fine by a quick test - Try `DF <- structure(list(A = c(2L, 1L, NA, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L), B = c(3L, 2L, 
2L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))` and then `n <- 3; tail(filter(DF, rep(1,n), sides=1), -(n-1))` vs. `setNames(as.data.frame(na.omit(filter(DF, rep(1, 3)))), names(DF))`

Comment: OK. But this is not a part of the problem as stated.

Comment: Thank you so much, rollsum() function works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `data.table` option using `frollsum`, e.g.,

```
> na.omit(setDT(df)[,lapply(.SD,frollsum,5)])
    A  B
1: 13 19
2: 16 22
3: 17 25
```

or

```
> na.omit(setDT(df)[,setNames(frollsum(.SD,5),names(.SD))])
    A  B
1: 13 19
2: 16 22
3: 17 25
```